# clickhouse - how get count datetime per 1minute or 1day ,

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table in [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/). for keep statistics and metrics.

and structure is:

```
datetime|metric_name|metric_value
```

I want to keep statistics and limit number of accesses in 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day and so on. So I need event counts in last minute, hour or day for every metric_name and I want to prepare statistics in a chart.

I do not know how to make a query. I get the count of metrics statistics based on the exact for example 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day and so on.

I used to work on [inflxdb](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM `TABLE` WHERE `metric_name`=`metric_value` AND time >= now() - 1h GROUP BY time(5m) fill(0)
```

In fact, I want to get the number of each metric per 5 minutes in the previous 1 hour.

I do not know how to use aggregations for this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ClickHouse has functions for generating Date/DateTime group buckets such as toStartOfWeek, toStartOfHour, toStartOfFiveMinute. You can also use `intDiv` function to manually divide value ranges. However the `fill` feature is still in the roadmap.

For example, you can rewrite the influx sql without the fill in ClickHouse like this,

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM `TABLE` WHERE `metric_name`=`metric_value` AND 
time >= now() - 1h GROUP BY toStartOfFiveMinute(time)
```

You can also refer to this discussion https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/379

## update

There is a `timeSlots` function that can help generating empty buckets. Here is a working example

```
SELECT
    slot,
    metric_value_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT
        toStartOfFiveMinute(datetime) AS slot,
        SUM(metric_value) AS metric_value_sum
    FROM metrics
    WHERE (metric_name = 'k1') AND (datetime >= (now() - toIntervalHour(1)))
    GROUP BY slot
)
ANY RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT arrayJoin(timeSlots(now() - toIntervalHour(1), toUInt32(3600), 300)) AS slot
) USING (slot)
```

Comment: Thank you.In your opinion, to fill in empty values. Is the following method suitable and optimal? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325639/1348284

Comment: Thank you for update! how can i use intDiv instead toStartOfFiveMinute for any ranges? For example, for the past 2 minutes every 10 seconds.

Comment: Here is the expression that rounds to every 10 seconds `toDateTime(intDiv(toUInt32(now()), 10) * 10);`  hope you get the idea

Comment: This query:  `SELECT SUM(value) FROM TABLE WHERE metric_name = metric_value AND 
time >= now() - 1h GROUP BY toStartOfFiveMinute(time)`

returns an exception: `DB::Exception: Column created_at is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY..`