# ORDER BY WITH FILL on an empty result

Tags: clickhouse

`ORDER BY WITH FILL` doesn't work if the result is empty:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM table
WHERE 1 != 1
ORDER BY val WITH FILL FROM 1 TO 5
```

```
Ok.
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.173 sec.
```

Most probably because `ORDER BY` is not involved in execution here.

Is there a way to make work, or the only workaround is to use `UNION` like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238568/how-to-group-by-time-bucket-in-clickhouse-and-fill-missing-data-with-nulls-0s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a mix of both. Union all with a default value you can filter at the end and the `FILL` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 0 AS number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number
    FROM numbers(10)
    WHERE 1 != 1
  )
  ORDER BY number ASC WITH FILL FROM 1 TO 5
)
WHERE number != 0

┌─number─┐
│      1 │
│      2 │
│      3 │
│      4 │
└────────┘
```